# Can I create a global object and assign its value globally in VBA?

Tags: vba, global

I've had no trouble creating a new object globally, but when I try to assign values to the object globally, a Compile Error pops up (Expected end of statement).

Just started with VBA, I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.  Couldn't find anything about this online.

I've listed the Class and Sub below.

**Class**

```
'Class name: FileManager
Option Explicit

Public FileName, Path As String
Public Printer As Integer
```

**Module Variable declaration**

```
Public Scripts As Worksheet

Public CDM As New FileManager
Public CDM.Printer = 1 '<--Where the error occurs
```

Comment: I would recommend that you read [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx), which explains why `As New FileManager` is a bad idea, and which also details how your class should use `Property Get`/`Property Let` instead of public variables.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, That website really helped out!  Guess I'll be using Property from now on.

Comment: You didnt need the public in the sub.  Properties also good though. :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - I mistyped - I declared the object in the beginning (not in a sub!), where the module variables were declared, because I wanted the object to be global